# Select-Object with System.Management.Automation doesn't return selected properties

Tags: c#, powershell

I'm using the System.Management.Automation.dll to fetch mailboxes in c# with Select-Object to return only the fields that I need.  Unfortunately, the returned result is a list of PSObjects with a single property and a null value.  The properties are not correctly being mapped onto the returned PSObjects.

Runspace Pipeline Setup:

```
var o365ConnectionUri = "https://outlook.office365.com/powershell-liveid/";
var exchangeModuleUri = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/powershell/Microsoft.Exchange";
var connectionInfo = new WSManConnectionInfo(new Uri(o365ConnectionUri), exchangeModuleUri, credentials)
{
    AuthenticationMechanism = AuthenticationMechanism.Basic
};
var runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(connectionInfo);
runspace.Open();
var pipeline = runspace.CreatePipeline()
```

Command Execution:

```
var getMailboxesCmd = new Command("Get-Mailbox");
getMailboxesCmd.Parameters.Add("ResultSize", "unlimited");

var fieldsToSelect = new[]
{
    "RecipientTypeDetails",
    "PrimarySmtpAddress",
    "DisplayName"
};
var sparseMailboxesCmd = new Command("Select-Object");
sparseMailboxesCmd.Parameters.Add("Property", string.Join(",", fieldsToSelect));

pipeline.Commands.Add(getMailboxesCmd);
pipeline.Commands.Add(sparseMailboxesCmd );

var result = pipeline.Invoke();
```

Now I would expect the result to be a list of PSObjects with properties for `RecipientTypeDetails`, `PrimarySmtpAddress`, and `DisplayName`.  However, as I mentioned above one property is returned named `RecipientTypeDetails,PrimarySmtpAddress,DisplayName` with a null value.

[image: Properties Not Returned]

As far as I can tell this must be a bug in the System.Management.Automation.dll, has anyone else dealt with this or found a workaround?

Comment: Add the parameter "Property" as array, not as concatenated string

Comment: Thanks Theo, that definitely was the issue.  Feel free to add that as an answer and I'll give you the points for it.  On another note, the returned property values are PSObject instead of object so i'm having a little trouble casting them.  Do you know the proper way to cast PSObject to the value types?

Comment: I just used .ToString then used Convert.ChangeType on the string, i'm not sure if that will work for everything but it's working for me for now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Select-Object` command when used with parameter `Property` takes a single property name as string or a string array of propertynames as argument.

In your case, you are concatenating the three properties to become one single string by doing `string.Join(",", fieldsToSelect)`. 
This boils down to asking the `Select-Object` to find one single property named "RecipientTypeDetails,PrimarySmtpAddress,DisplayName" and of course that does not exist (returns `null`).

To fix this, simply add the **array** of property names to the command:

```
var sparseMailboxesCmd = new Command("Select-Object");
sparseMailboxesCmd.Parameters.Add("Property", fieldsToSelect);
```

As for your latest comment:
`Select-Object` will return PSObject(s) where each object contains the properties you have added to the command.

To get (expand) the actual values from these PSObjects, your solution using `.ToString` would work because the properties in this case are all of type string.
Although I'm not really into C#, I think this would also work to get the property values from the PSObjects:

```
object.Properties["RecipientTypeDetails"].Value
object.Properties["PrimarySmtpAddress"].Value
object.Properties["DisplayName"].Value
```

Comment: I am actually accessing the property values as you suggest but instead of containing an object type they contain another PSObject.  Usually property values contain a base object which can be casted to any value type so it's a little unusual.

Comment: @NicholasJ.Markkula Strange indeed. As I said, I'm not really into C# but from your feedback I learn.